# Emacs/OSX Default font setting does not persist

Tags: macos, emacs, fonts, customization

I'm using Emacs 23.2. When I change the default font using Options --> Set Default Font... it correctly switches to the font that I select. I then do Options --> Save Options to make it permanent.

It writes a stanza to the end of my .emacs, but it's empty, doesn't contain anything about the font. Also, in the minibuffer it says "Loading battery...done" which seems a bit weird. And when I restart Emacs, the font is back to the default, which is Monaco. Similarly, changing the font size does not persist, but other (non-font-related) customizations do persist.

Anyone seen this? Anyone know how to make the font setting permanent?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try `M-x customize-face RET default`, adjust to your liking, then 'Save for future sessions'.

**Edit:** 
For example, that adds the following stanza to my `(custom-set-faces)` in .emacs:

```
(custom-set-faces
  '(default ((t (:inherit nil :stipple nil :background "White" :foreground "Black" :inverse-video nil :box nil :strike-through nil :overline nil :underline nil :slant normal :weight normal :height 130 :width normal :family "Consolas"))))
  ...
```

If all you want to so is set the font size & family (13pt Consolas in this example), this appears to be sufficient:

```
  '(default ((t (:height 130 :family "Consolas"))))
```

Comment: This worked. It seems that setting the font fails when it attempts to use the standard Apple font selection dialog panel, but works with this method (where you type in the name of the font, rather than selecting it from a dialog).

Comment: Actually, the Options -> Set Default Font menu item seems to only affect the current frame, so in a way it's not surprising that is isn't persisted.

Comment: Ah it makes sense now. I was misled by seeing the 'Save Options' menu item immediately below the 'Set Default Font' item, and knowing that you need to 'Save Options' to make any of the other customizations persist.

Comment: I alter the font after emacs startup, and  then I M-x customize-face and click apply and save, so it work next startup ,thinks a lot

Comment: @bosmacs the menu item works and persists in linux, so the fact that it doesn't work in macos is a bug not a feature

Answer (score 9):

Only way I got it to work was to modify manually the .emacs file:

```
(custom-set-faces                                                                                    
 '(default ((t (:height 150 :family "Menlo"))))
 )
```

PS: I'm on Yosemite

Comment: (set-frame-font "Menlo 10")

Comment: i believe the custom-set-foobar functions were not intended to be input manually into .emacs, rather they are supposed to be generated automatically by M-x customize-foobar dialogs

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I think it is because Emacs does not have the permission to edit the *custom.el* file. This file is read-only in Emacs.

So I use `sudo vim ~/.emacs.d/custom.el` to edit it, and it works well.