# How do I change Emacs' default font size and font type?

Tags: emacs, emacs23

I am using Emacs 23.3. How can I change the font size and font type?

Comment: A similar question about changing the default font size **and** saving it to `.emacs`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/294664/94687

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You can use the menu bar. Go to `Options`->`Set Default Font...`.

After you choose a font, don't forget to press `Options`->`Save Options`—otherwise your new font will not be saved after you close Emacs.

Comment: This doesn't work (perhaps it used to?) It only changes the font for the current frame, and it does not get saved for future sessions. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4822066/699305) for a method that works.

Comment: @alexis: It still works for me on Emacs-24.2. Here'a [screenshot](http://jelv.is/emacs-fonts-so.png). (Sorry for the hideous font choice :P.) It also saved properly when I restarted Emacs. Perhaps you have a configuration difference on your end or something?

Comment: My version is barely different: I've got GNU Emacs 24.3.1 on OS X, and it doesn't work. Clearly something is different, but see also the question and discussion at [the answer I linked to](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4822066/699305). That approach saved the day for me. I guess the conclusion is "YMMV".

Comment: Didn't work for Emacs 24.4 on OS X 10.10.5 either. But direct change to ~/.emacs works.

Comment: If you hid the menu bar but still would like to use a GUI font picker with previews, you can use `M-x menu-set-font`.

Comment: Or you can still press F10 and select Options->Set Default Font menu item.

Comment: Emacs 26.3, on OS X, seeing the same behavior: "Save for future Sessions" direct from the menus doesn't work, but M-x customize-face RET default RET then making some change (because the shown value is what I picked from the "Set default Font" menu), and telling customize to save it wrote the correct `custom-set-faces` clause to my init.el file.

It's as though customize on Mac doesn't think anything is changed if you change the font via the menu, so it won't write anything out. Touching the value inside the customize buffer makes it think that a change really happened.

Comment: It worked fine on Emacs 27.1 [compiled from source on Ubuntu MATE 20.04 (Focal Fossa)](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2020/11/11/building-emacs-from-source-on-ubuntu-20-04/).

Comment: Still doesn't work in emacs 27 on mac os monterey. I was able to get the same behavior by `M-x customize-face default` and then changing the size there, but I had to make sure to UNcheck the background and foreground options there, otherwise `customize-theme` doesn't work

Comment: Emacs 28.0.91 on Mac OS 11.6.4.

Set Default Font worked for me. However to get it to persist, after you set the Font, you have to click Save Options in the menu.

I do recall that this didn't seem to work last time I tried with Emacs for OSX 27 last year. I'm using a custom compiled version of v. 28.

Answer (score 147):

You can also do the following in your `.emacs` file.

### Emacs 23.1

```
(set-frame-font "Inconsolata 12" nil t)
```

### Older versions of Emacs

```
(set-default-font "Inconsolata 12" nil t)
```

Comment: (set-default-font Fontname-Size) is now deprecated use (set-frame-font Fontname-Size)

Comment: You should also set the `FRAMES` argument to `t` to affect all frames, not just the current frame. `(set-frame-font Fontname-Size nil t)`

Comment: You can also run `describe-font` to determine current font (for example if it's set throught customize) or to figure out possible options for "full name"

Answer (score 13):

Get current font by:
`M-x describe-font`

**(Hit `Enter` if you see `Font name (default current choice for ASCII chars):` )**

This will show a list of attributes which can be set in `init.el`. After you've had a look the values, minimize the message buffer by `C-x 1`.

Now do a `M-x customize-face` and:

1. Scroll down to the "Default" section
2. Change the value of "Font Family"
3. Change the value of "Height"
4. Hit `Enter` on "State" and then 1 = Save for Future Sessions

Alternatively, in `init.el` you could have something like:

```
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :font "Monospace" :height 160)
```

**Note:** If you have a preset for window size (width and height), the `height` attribute of the font is going to interfere with that layout.

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04.2 emacs 27.2 example: `(set-face-attribute 'default nil :font "Ubuntu Medium" :height 160)` . Use `M-x menu-set-font` to get a pop-up and see the available fonts on your install.

Answer (score 8):

To get an extended list of customization use

> M-x customize-face RET

Answer (score 4):

Emacs 25.1 on macOS has Menlo 12 as default. I wanted to increase the size.

`C-x C-f` `~/.emacs`

Add this to end of the `~/.emacs` file:

> (set-default-font "Menlo 14")

To see the change take effect immediately while staying in `~/.emacs`:

`M-x eval-buffer [RET]`

Comment: This works for the FIRST file I open when launching emacs, but then subsequent buffers use the smaller font again.

Answer (score 4):

In my answer, I'll concentrate on setting the default font size through X resources. The use of X resources has already been mentioned in the answer mentioning `~/.Xdefaults`; I'll give more details (the same which I have already described in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/426914/4319. Apart from the height of the "default" "face" in Emacs, one can similarly set other font parameters.

To set a specific default font height for Emacs, I have put into `/etc/X11/Xresources-site` (`/etc/X11/Xresources` is also OK, though can be overwritten by your distro):

```
Emacs.default.attributeHeight: 94
```

This would affect also remote X clients which are Emacs (e.g., emacs started on a remote host via ssh).

`/etc/X11/Xresources-site` and `/etc/X11/Xresources` (and probably `~/.Xresources` and `~/.Xdefaults`) are usually read at the start of your X session; to affect your current X resources immediately, run something like `xrdb -merge /etc/X11/Xresources-site`. The X resources can be viewed by `xrdb -query`.

Actually, in my case, `/etc/X11/Xresources-site` is being read thanks to a line in `/etc/X11/Xresources` (which is read by the start scripts):

```
#include "/etc/X11/Xresources-site"
```

so `/etc/X11/Xresources` is the thing that is read for sure.

There are also some files with the same syntax which are read each time an X program like emacs starts. In my case, they are: `~/.Xdefaults-MY_HOST_NAME`, `/etc/X11/app-defaults/Emacs` (only for emacs-athena, not for emacs-gtk3), `/usr/share/X11/app-defaults/Emacs` etc. (But I like the idea of loaded X resources more -- shown with `xrdb -query`; so that remote X clients read the same X resources.)

Other X resources which Emacs understands are described at https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Table-of-Resources.html#Table-of-Resources.

Emacs 24.3 had [a bug](https://bugzilla.altlinux.org/show_bug.cgi?id=34583) which made it not honor the attributes for the default face coming from the X resources, such as in my example above. This was [fixed](https://git.gnu.io/gnu/emacs/commit/f5e4494cd06f7624382f815585419f489bfe36c3?view=inlineh) since 24.4.

Answer (score 3):

The Emacs way

1. M-x `customize-group`
2. Enter `faces`
3. Click on "Basic Faces"
4. Open / Expand "Default"
5. Change the font name (like "Inconsolata") and deselect "foundry"
6. Click "Apply and save"

Comment: *What* makes it the Emacs way, in particular?

Answer (score 2):

If you use Linux/X11, you may need to set this in `~/.Xdefaults`.  I
have set the font there since the other answers here have no effect.

I'm able to see available font settings by running in Emacs:
`helm-select-xfont`

Then I start typing `Conso` and I see entries like:

```
-Consolas-normal-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1
...
```

So then I put it into `~/.Xdefaults`, setting size `12` as:

```
Emacs.font: xft:-*-Consolas-normal-normal-normal-*-12-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1
```

and restart Emacs.

Answer (score 2):

Simply press `M-x`, and then type in `set-frame-font`. All available fonts which exist in your machine will be displayed.

Choose the one you look for. I use this way to change font-type in my Emacs so simply; rather than altering the `.spacemacs` or `.emacs` file.