# how to set ttf font in emacs

Tags: emacs, fonts

I have installed liberation-fonts package and xfontsel sees its fonts. But emacs not. Why? If possible I would do without X resources file.

```
(set-default-font "-*-liberation serif-*-*-*-*-17-*-*-*-*-*-*-*")
```

p.s. I trying it on gentoo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also try `set-default-font`, like this:

```
(set-default-font "Liberation Mono-13")
```

or

```
(set-default-font "Liberation Mono-13:bold")
```

in your `.emacs` file (the docs for this function advise using `set-frame-font` instead, but `set-default-font` still works in Emacs 24).

You might find these links interesting:

- [How do I change emacs default font size and font type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026713/how-do-i-change-emacs-default-font-size-and-font-type)
- [How to set the font size in Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294664/how-to-set-the-font-size-in-emacs)
- [relevant Emacs Wiki page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SetFonts)

Comment: set-default-font: Font `Liberation Mono-13' is not defined.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu, which has this particular font installed by default. You probably need to install the font or use a different font that is present on your system.

Comment: It installed on my system and I can see it in xfontsel. But emacs not see... but emacs see terminus-font. wtf? :)

Comment: Try shift-left click in an Emacs buffer and select "Change Buffer Font..." from the popup menu. You should see a list of fonts you can select from. Also, make sure you're running Emacs 23 or 24 - I don't remember what works in Emacs 22 or less.

Answer (score 1):

A nice way to set fonts in Emacs is through `~/.Xdefaults`:

```
Emacs.font: Inconsolata:size=16:antialise:true
Emacs.fontBackend: xft
```