# How to change font size in emacs 21.4.1 in red hat 5.8 tikanga

Tags: emacs, fonts

I'm using `emacs 21.4.1` which is default installation on `red hat linux 5.8 (tikanga)`.
I've tried suggestions mentioned in [How do I change emacs default font size and font type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026713/how-do-i-change-emacs-default-font-size-and-font-type),
however, none of them are working for me.

1. There is no such `Options->Set Default Font....` tab.
2. Using `set-default-font "Inconsolata 12"` gives error: `font "incosolata 12" is not defined` while loading `.emacs`.
3. If i try changing the font using Font Menu (`shift + mouse-left-click`), then most of the options result in all characters modified into "rectangular boxes" - in short nothing is readable.

Kindly help.

Comment: @chris: No. Even Emacs 20 (and maybe earlier) supports TrueType fonts and `set-default-font`. I'm using 20 right now with a TrueType font. It depends, rather, on your platform.

Comment: @Drew, I'll defer to you on that. I wasn't able to find a reliable source but if you have version 20 running that's good enough for me :-).

Comment: @Drew: I agree it might be platform related. However, its a corporate setup and we do not have root permissions. Can you kindly guide on how to diagnose the problem. The only thing that works for me "Font Menu (shift+mouse-left-click) => FontSet => Standard: 16-dot medium". My .Xdefaults file has emacs*font : 9x15. Any thing else result in characters getting converted to empty blocks. - mukesh

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a solution or guide to diagnosing the problem. Hopefully someone else will be ablt to help. The first thing to try might be to see if you have the same problem when choosing other fonts. If you have the problem only for certain fonts then maybe you just cannot use those fonts with your version of Emacs on your platform. If you cannot use any fonts then that is a worse problem. Try to distinguish between the two problems, for a start. That could help others help you.